# HIGHCHARTS, Replace zero with 0.1 >

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

How can I do something like this? I want to replace the zero with something else. Highcharts (I just edited the picture). Thank you so much

[image]

Comment: You mean just changing the axis label, not the point value itself?

Comment: Yes Sir. I just want to replace the zero value with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To alter certain axis label values to show something else you could set a `axis.labels.formatter` function ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter)). For example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0r5a7guo/6/)):

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            if(this.value == 0)
                return '0.1 >'
            else
                return this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Here, if the value is `0` we output the label as `0.1 >`, otherwise we return the default label.